# Sort a file and then print out part of it in original order - Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to print out 5 users with the highest UID, but the lines have to be in the original order, as they are in /etc/passwd

I am able to do in only in a sorted way:

```
sort -t":" -k3 -n /etc/passwd | tail -n5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `cat -n` to get line numbers along with the output and then do a sort at the end on those line numbers.

```
cat -n /etc/passwd | sort -t":" -k3 -n | tail -n5 | sort -n
```